# WSO2ESB has Bug According to this Configuration

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

i am using 4.6.0 WSO2ESB as per my configuration its working some scenarios but giving unkonow faults is it a fulfilled tool.  i tried in many ways this below scenarios is i am passing wrong value which primary key dependant but WSO2 esb unable to handle this even i tried all the properties .if any one  knows about WSO2 enough well help me i am struck past too many days about this small issue my insertion is working but if any primary key violation error is thier in WSO2DSS ESb unable to send it to  fault sequence i added

```
 <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

eventhough its giving like this error in EsB when dss is off mode its passing to fault sequence correctly my error is why it will occuerss

[201

```
3-03-19 12:01:27,099] ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,167]
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.buildNext(OMDocumentImpl.java:135)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:122)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:343)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:58)
    at org.jaxen.util.DescendantAxisIterator.hasNext(DescendantAxisIterator.java:101)
    at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultStep.evaluate(DefaultStep.java:152)
    at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultLocationPath.evaluate(DefaultLocationPath.java:140)
    at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultAbsoluteLocationPath.evaluate(DefaultAbsoluteLocationPath.java:113)
    at org.jaxen.expr.DefaultXPathExpr.asList(DefaultXPathExpr.java:102)
    at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodesForContext(BaseXPath.java:674)
    at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.selectNodes(BaseXPath.java:213)
    at org.jaxen.BaseXPath.evaluate(BaseXPath.java:172)
    at org.apache.synapse.util.xpath.SynapseXPath.stringValueOf(SynapseXPath.java:297)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator.getResultValue(PropertyMediator.java:299)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.PropertyMediator.mediate(PropertyMediator.java:95)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:223)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:443)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:166)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:217)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Illegal processing instruction target ("xml"); xml (case insensitive) is reserved by the specs.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,167]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructWfcException(StreamScanner.java:606)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwParseError(StreamScanner.java:479)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readPIPrimary(BasicStreamReader.java:3903)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2037)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.closeContentTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2886)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2629)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1062)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    ... 27 more
[2013-03-19 12:02:22,573]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2013-03-19 12:02:22,572+0530]
[2013-03-19 12:02:27,101]  WARN - SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: 127.0.0.1:58904->127.0.0.1:828
```

for my other configuartions like Proxy reff is

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15474647/how-we-can-resolve-this-issue-in-wso2esb-or-wso2dss
[How can i handle this in Wso2ESB which is not passing Respone to Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15471178/how-can-i-handle-this-in-wso2esb-which-is-not-passing-respone-to-client)

Comment: i am previously working on oracle soa i just switched to this one but this tool has many issues ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are using DSS in this integration too. In your Data Service can you disable streaming and try again. to do so uncheck "enable streaming" at the Data Service configuration.

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/DSS301/RDBMS

(refer 2nd image).

Comment: thanx for quick replay really great..i hope it will work..i will get back to u as soon as

Comment: thanx very much Shelan u really awesome boss i am trying this for last from  15 days thank u very much from bottom of my heart..

Comment: Really glad to be helpful :).